# Transform array of rank 2 to array of rank 1

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

I have the following minimal example:

```
      program main

      double precision, dimension(3)   :: rankone
      double precision, dimension(3,1) :: ranktwo

      double precision, dimension(3)   :: output

      rankone = 1
      ranktwo = 2

      output = rankone + ranktwo

      print *, 'output: ', output

      end program main
```

Is there a function like `squeeze` in Matlab that removes the singleton dimension from the variable `ranktwo`. I'm looking for something like

```
      output = rankone + squeeze(ranktwo)
```

If not, is there any workaround for this setting?

Are there any differences between the various versions of Fortran regarding this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
output = rankone + reshape(ranktwo,[3])
```

then look at the documentation for `reshape` to see what is going on.  You could also write

```
output = rankone + ranktwo(:,1)
```

which slices a 1D array out of `ranktwo`.  In my experience `reshape` usually causes an array copy so there may be a memory-use-efficiency argument for preferring the second version.

No, there are no differences between Fortran versions regarding this problem, a 3x1 array is not the same shape as a 1D array of length 3.

Comment: Thanks. Your second suggestion doesn't help me, because in the code where I actually had this problem the value of rank two is returned by a function. Today memory usage issues aren't a real problem anymore. Do you think using reshape also slows down the runtime?

Comment: What I think about reshape affecting runtime doesn't matter a damn, what you measure is all you need care about.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in F2003 you may point to your rank one array with a rank two pointer, like this:

```
program main

  double precision, dimension(3), target   :: rankone
  double precision, dimension(3,1) :: ranktwo
  double precision, dimension(3,1)   :: output
  double precision, pointer :: pp(:,:)

  rankone(:) = 1
  ranktwo(:,:) = 2
  pp(1:size(rankone),1:1) => rankone

  output = pp + ranktwo

  print *, 'output: ', output

end program main
```

The other direction (pointing to a rank two array by a rank one pointer) only works in Fortran 2008, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ingenious.  But you've changed `output` to rank 2, in the original it is rank 1.  One could use a rank 1 pointer to point to a rank 1 slice of the rank 2 array.

Comment: Yes, indeed, good point. The original post is somewhat unclear about what should be achieved and what is allowed to be changed.